# RestAssured : How to execute RestAssured test cases on different nodes using Grid?

Tags: grid, rest-assured

I’m just keen to know as in how to execute RestAssured test cases on different nodes using Grid? Or is it even possible to do it? If it’s possible what are the ways and how can we achieve this? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand under `Grid` you mean `Selenium Grid`. From its name, we understand that we can only manage Selenium servers.

If you have combined (web + API) tests and you want to run it in a few threads you can use Docker.

For example, for Java, you can use `Testcontainers` or `avast/gradle-docker-compose-plugin`.